# Using Class.forName to load a Weka class at runtime

Tags: java, string, weka

I don't want to hardcode the name of a Weka classifier into my Java like this:

```
Classifier cls = new J48();
```

Where Classifier is a Weka class.

Rather I would prefer to store value "J48" in a database table varchar column.

Any ideas as to how to convert a Java String containing "J48" to the Weka type though? I am unsuccessfully trying things like:

```
cls = Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48;");
```

J48 is the name of a Weka class for decision trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick solution:

```
Object obj = Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").newInstance();
Classifier cls = Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").cast(obj);
```

J48 should have 0 param constructor.

Answer (score 1):

There's a better one-line version

```
Classifier classifier = AbstractClassifier.forName(className, options);
```

Or the following for newer versions of Weka

```
Classifier classifier = Classifier.forName(className, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is technically the same answer, but just a shorter *one-line* version

```
Classifier cls = (Classifier) Class.forName("weka.classifiers.trees.J48").newInstance();
```